# Flutter - Use Custom colors and themes in ThemeData

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to use custom colors and themes in ThemeData. I know that I can define them in a separate file and import that file and use them. But I want those colors to work when changing the dark and light themes.
Currently I have separate dark and light themes that I toggle. Is there anyway to define custom colors in dark and light ThemeData separately?

AppTheme.dart:

```
class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  // Light Theme
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,

    actionButtonColor: Colors.black, // Like this
  );

  // Dark Theme
  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.grey[850],
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],

    actionButtonColor: Colors.red, // Like this
  );
}
```

App.dart

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Dashboard(),
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you already have the answer in your own question, what you've been doing in the code sample is right, and is legal. And by the word legal, I mean the code will work and yield the result as you expected, of course, except for the part `actionButtonColor` property, because that property is not part of the `ThemeData` api.

Or, if you are asking how to use that custom `actionButtonColor` property in your theme data, you can't. Because it is a predefined widget to use with material theming. That `actionButton` should just consume an existing property from the theme. But if you really need to do, you can use experimental extension methods in dart 2.7 like,

```dart
extension MyColorScheme on ColorScheme {
  Color get actionButtonColor => const Colors.red;
}

ActionButtonComponent(
    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.actionButtonColor, 
);
```

But still, you won't be able to have a different colored scheme for another `ThemeData` like dark and light themes, when using with extension methods. You might want to look into [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16487).

I hope it helps.

Comment: is there any alternative to : "But still, you won't be able to have a different colored scheme for another ThemeData like dark and light themes, when using with extension methods"

Answer (score 4):

You could look into extensions for ThemeData, i have found it very useful and simple.

```
    extension LightThemeEx on ThemeData{
      Color get appSubTitleColor{
        return Color(0xFF5F6368);
      }
    }
```

On it you can create custom colors; implementation would be very similar on your widgets:

```
      Theme.of(context).appSubTitleColor
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will try to solve your problem without extending ThemeData but by using AppTheme class itself for providing theme dependent custom colours.

You will need

1. a static getter that procures colour based on value of
2. a static field that stores current theme state in the AppTheme class.

You can use a boolean as the static field and you can change its value when you toggle the theme from somewhere in the app.

Modified AppTheme class as such:

```dart
class AppTheme {
  AppTheme._();

  // Light Theme
  static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.grey[100],
      brightness: Brightness.light,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white);
  

  // Dark Theme
  static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.grey[850],
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[900]);
  
  
  // Custom colors
  static bool _isThemeDark = false;

  static set isThemeDark(bool value) {_isThemeDark = value;}

  static get actionButtonColor => _isThemeDark
    ? Colors.green 
    : Colors.red;
}
```

You can also use [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), or any state management solution, for updating theme and colours on the fly with ease.

```dart
class AppTheme with ChangeNotifier {
.
.
.
  set isThemeDark(bool value) {
  _isThemeDark = value; 
  notifyListner();
  }
}
```

Use example:

```dart
void main(){
  AppTheme.isThemeDark=true;
  print(AppTheme.actionButtonColor);
}
```